# 3D array as cv::mat and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, c++11

When I use cv::Mat is it the same as np.array((3,2,3))?

```
cv::Mat mat_32f_C3(mat.rows, mat.cols, CV_32FC3);
mat_32f_C3.at<cv::Vec3f>(0,0) = cv::Vec3f(1,1,1); 
mat_32f_C3.at<cv::Vec3f>(0,1) = cv::Vec3f(2,2,2);
mat_32f_C3.at<cv::Vec3f>(1,0) = cv::Vec3f(3,3,3);
mat_32f_C3.at<cv::Vec3f>(1,1) = cv::Vec3f(4,4,4);
mat_32f_C3.at<cv::Vec3f>(2,0) = cv::Vec3f(5,5,5);
mat_32f_C3.at<cv::Vec3f>(2,1) = cv::Vec3f(6,6,6);
```

I am not sure if the `cv::Vec3f` represents RGB in a color image.

In python I would write

```
broadcast = np.zeros((3,2,3))
i1 = np.arange(1, 7, 1).reshape((3,2))
result = i1 + broadcast

output array([[[[1., 2.],
         [3., 4.],
         [5., 6.]],
        [[1., 2.],
         [3., 4.],
         [5., 6.]],
        [[1., 2.],
         [3., 4.],
         [5., 6.]]]])
```

Are these examples the same?

Comment: Not exactly, but almost :) -- `np.array(3,2,3)` will cause a syntax error, `np.zeros((3,2,3))` will use `np.float64` as datatype. To make it equivalent to the C++ code, you want `np.float32`. `cv::Vec3f` matches `CV_32FC3`. It could be used to represent pixel colors in a 3 channel image (e.g. RGB).

Comment: ok. thanks. You clarified my question :)